# SIGSEGV error when getting advice list in SKMaps

Tags: android, segmentation-fault, skmaps, skobbler-maps

I am getting a SIGSEGV error when attempting to get the advice list in SKMaps. The same code I currently have was not getting an error until recently even though it has been unchanged. The only change that was made was updating a couple Android libraries to more recent versions. I am using SKMaps version 3.0.0. The line of code that is causing the error is:

```
SKRouteManager.getInstance().getAdviceListForRouteByUniqueId(routeId, SKMaps.SKDistanceUnitType.DISTANCE_UNIT_MILES_FEET);
```

Are there any solutions or ways I can fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by deleting the Advisor folder within SKMaps.zip